# squid access.log delete entries older than 6 months

Tags: shell-script, perl, squid, logrotate

Squid generates a log of the accessed sites by the users.
I want to delete the entries in the `/var/squid/logs/access.log`, which are older than 6 months.

I would execute the script each week. I have thought of a perl script or any like that.

**Here is how the `access.log` looks like:**

[image]

**Entries are generated like this:**

```
IP - - [15/Oct/2011:02:04:32 -400]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual solution for this problem is to use rotate the logfiles so that the current logfile only contains current entries, rather than removing outdated entries from the file.

This is all handled by the `logrotate` program.
The following configuration should do approximately what you want.
It will keep the last 6 months of log entries from `/var/squid/logs/access.log`, rotating the files weekly.

```
/var/squid/logs/access.log {
    weekly
    rotate 26
    missingok
    nocreate
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        test ! -e /var/run/squid.pid || /usr/sbin/squid -k rotate
    endscript
}
```

If you do care about the data in your logfiles, you shouldn't modify them.

Comment: I want to run a wifi hotspot and because of the data preversation law in Germany I have to store the log files for 6 months. I know the best solution would be a syslog server but I want to store the data locally on the harddrive.

Comment: the proposed solution will work for that: it will keep logged data for 26 weeks (= 6 months) and then delete it. you could also modify it to store the logfiles for a bit longer, just to be sure you do have the logs when they are requested.

Comment: Is it also possible to provide a version with `newsyslog` ?

Answer (score 0):

A solution with [`newsyslog`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=newsyslog.conf&sektion=5):

```
# logfile                 [owner:group]    mode    count    when   flags
/var/squid/logs/access.log root             644     26       $W0D0  JN
```

The logfile will be rotated 26 times before it will be deleted. `$W0D0` indicates that I will be rotated each sunday at `0:00` o'clock.

The flag `J` indicates that newsyslog should compress the rotated file using `bzip2`.

The flag `N` indicates that there is no process which needs to be signaled.